# Website section not appearing with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to webscrape the abstract part of this website:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urlLink = 'https://www.cfapubs.org/doi/abs/10.2469/faj.v74.n4.2'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5, verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')
```

and when I search for:

```
    soup2.find_all("div", {"class": "abstractSection"})
```

I do not get anything, whereas this is the part i'm interested in.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure where you found this `page_link` to make use of. Try the below approach to get the content you wanna parse.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urlLink = 'https://www.cfapubs.org/doi/abs/10.2469/faj.v74.n4.2'

page_response = requests.get(urlLink,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')
name = soup.find(class_="hlFld-ContribAuthor").find("a").text
abstract = soup.find(class_="abstractSection").find("p").text
print(f'Name : {name}\nAbstract : {abstract}')
```

If you want to use selector then try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urlLink = 'https://www.cfapubs.org/doi/abs/10.2469/faj.v74.n4.2'

page_response = requests.get(urlLink,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')
name = soup.select_one(".hlFld-ContribAuthor a").text
abstract = soup.select_one(".abstractSection p").text
print(f'Name : {name}\nAbstract : {abstract}')
```

Output:

```
Name : Charles D. Ellis, CFA
Abstract :  One of the consequences of the shift in corporate retirement plans from defined benefit           to defined contribution is widespread retirement insecurity. Although most people in the           top one-third of economic affluence will be fine, for the other two-thirds—particularly           the bottom one-third—the problem is a serious threat. We can prevent this painful           future if we act sensibly and soon by raising the alarm with our corporate and government           leaders.
```

Finally, if you do not wish to see the gap between text within `abstract` then replace the line with `abstract = ' '.join(soup.find(class_="abstractSection").find("p").text.split())`.

Comment: Thank you very much, would you know how to get the name just above the abstract part too? he's called "Charles D. Ellis, CFA"